# I am losing control and unable to Debug

Tags: c++, destructor, friend

```
class Base
{
private:
    int nID;
    friend int fnDeleteBase(Base*  base);
public: 
    Base( int baseID):nID(baseID) { cout << "Base Constructed with value" << endl; }
    Base () : nID(5){cout << "Base Constructed WITHOUT value" << endl; }
    ~Base() { cout << "Base class object killed " << endl; }
};

int fnDeleteBase(Base* base)                           // Line 1
{
    delete base;                                       // Line 2 - important
    cout << "Base object deleted " << endl; 
    return (1);
}

int main()
{
    Base aBase;                                        // Line 3 
    try
    {
        int i = fnDeleteBase(&aBase);                  // Line 4 
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        cout << "Exception handled " << endl;
    }

    return (0);
}
```

The above code snippet I was debugging. I am unable to Step into at Line 2 where I am deleting the base object. as soon as I try to step into or run over the line 2, the control goes and I have to kill the debugging or execution

The output I get is:

```
Base Constructed (any of the construction is valid) 
Base class Object killed
```

However everything works fine and  if Line 3 is changed to `Base * aBase = new Base();`. The output on console is:

```
Base Constructed (any of the construction is valid) 
Base class Object killed 
Base object Deleted
```

Can somebody share the technical details behind the two?

Comment: what programming environment are you using, Rajesh?

Comment: visual studio ultimate 2010

Comment: BTW I first tried fnDeleteBase with argument as reference to base. the result was same as first case . then i tried with pointer.

Answer (score 4):

You should **only** use `delete` on pointers that were constructed using `new` (or pointers that were assigned to other pointers that were constructed using `new`), no exceptions (that I know of).

Using `delete` on anything else (which is what happens in the first case, since the parameter of `fnDeleteBase` is a pointer to `Base aBase`, which is not a pointer and there is no `new` keyword there) results in undefined behaviour.

Explaining what exactly the compiler does won't really be helpful as, with undefined behaviour, this can differ from compiler to compiler. And it should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: just curious, it is object oriented programming. Should it make a difference in how i create an object. I just created a pointer to the object and delete it.

Comment: Thanks Duke, your response makes sense. Now I got it too, with new we create objects in the heap while local scope object gets deleted themselves and delete is required for objects in heap